A better way to check for non falsy values in JS/TS?
I am posting to see if anyone has a cleaner way of checking for non-false values in JS/TS files.
Over the years, I've had several attempts of writing cleaner if statements to check for non-falsy values as it triggers me how they all do the same thing but are pretty lengthy and end up taking half of some code files.
I tried creating functions and typing them in different ways to encapsulate logging and then throwing errors, but TS doesn't accept this as a safe check. So far, the only thing satisfying the check is a standard if statement, with the error thrown directly in the body.
Is there no better, less verbose way of handling these repetitive checks while maintaining safety?
Stadandard checks
 // Not falsy check
     if (!plan) {
        Log.log.stripe_webhook("Plan not found");
        throw new Error("Plan not found");
      }

  // Another not falsy check
      if (!currentUser.email) {
          Log.log.stripe_webhook("Current user does not have an email");
         throw new Error("Current user does not have an email");
       }

Things I've tried
Helper functions. I tried several ones over time, but here is a basic example, which TS doesn't accept.
// Function to ensure no false values. TS does not accept this as safe.
            function ensureNotFalsy(
              condition: any,
              errorMessage: string
            ): void {
              if (!condition) {
                Log.log.stripe_webhook(errorMessage);
                throw new Error(errorMessage);
              }
            }

            // Not falsy checks
            ensureNotFalsy(orgRef, "Organization reference not found");
            ensureNotFalsy(orgRef?.organization, "Organization not found");
            ensureNotFalsy(
              orgRef!.organization!.id,
              "Organization ID not found"
            );

  // ...Code below will still throw errors saying these checked values could be undefined.


Adding the errors and handling in a const. Doesn't work either. TS, seems to require the error to be thrown in each if statement.
 // Put logic in a const. TS doesn't recognize it as a safe.
        const throwError = (message: string) => {
            Log.log.stripe_webhook(message);
            throw new Error(message);
         };

          // Checks to ensure not falsy. Doesn't work with TS.
          if (!plan) throwError("Plan not found");
          if (!currentUser.email)
          throwError("Current user does not have an email");

  // ...Code below will still throw errors saying these checked values could be undefined.

Screenshot example

"Is there no better, less verbose way of handling these repetitive checks while maintaining safety?" - the safe programming practice is to never have objects in intermediate state where they might have properties or not. Move more smaller specific objects rather than a large mutated object  with optional properties. That's why you feel the language "is working against you", you can make optionals ergonomic with ?. and ?? and keep consistent schemas for the rest of the stuff.

Also, you are describing assert and it performs a type guard (so it validates type wise the property you're worried about). It's just not a very common/popular way to write code in TS/JS.

Hi @BenjaminGruenbaum, thanks for replying!
As a reply to your first comment: I am quite strict when it comes to clean, well structured and non verbose code. I often spend 3/4 of my time structuring a file after I write logic, to ensure no redundancy and simplicity.
Quite often though, especially with step processes, new values are introduced in phases, and can't always be defined as single initial object. The situation I described rarely involves mutations, as I would usually type a mutated value to ensure typesafety.

Did you try assertion functions? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions

I don't feel like the language is working against me, I love TS, but these overfly simple if statements for nonfalsy values have been triggering me for years, as they all perform the exact same task, and take up so much space.
I rarely use if statements in general, I find that 90% of if statements I see in code can usually be rewritten in a clearer, more effective manner. And one thing I truly hate, is to go through files and see code written by a dev that contains hundreds of lines of if statements for processes that should be named, put in helpers, or use switch statements instead.

@GuillaumeBrunerie, I did try asssert, but TS also doens't recognize this as safe. When using assert to check for non falsy values, the proceeding code using these values, still considers them as being potentially undefined.
Here is the GPT answer on why this doesn't seem to work:
TypeScript's type system does not automatically infer non-nullability from assertions or similar checks by default. TypeScript treats assertions as any other function calls that don't return, but it doesn't understand that they confirm the existence or type of variables unless explicitly told so.

Assertion functions are designed exactly for this use case. The answer from ChatGPT doesn't make any sense.

Additionally, let's say you want to reduce the if statements by checking for multiple non falsy values in a single check.
When doing this, there is no direct way to return a customized error or log to state which value is undefined, as JS isn't aware of the name of a name value, so you end up having to throw a general error and log, which isn't always accepted in production code.
My favorite way to handle this is using Zod parsing, but its' not always possible to created a zod schemas for each value.

@GuillaumeBrunerie below is an example, based on the original code I shared, replacing the if statements with assert. Ts doesn't accept any of them.
```// Asserts check
        assert.ok(orgRef && orgRef.organization, "Organization not found");
        const plan = getPlanProductBy("stripe_price_id", stripePrice);
        assert.ok(plan, "Plan not found");

        try {
          await createSubscription({
            plan_id: plan.id, // TS considers this as possibly null
            organizationId: orgRef.organization?.id, // Same here```


Check my answer, assertion functions work. I’m not sure what you mean by assert.ok.

@GuillaumeBrunerie you're referring to this right? https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assertokvalue-message
Do you have an example?

@MaxPauwels No, I'm referring to assertion functions in Typescript, not in Node. See the link I gave above and in my answer.

@GuillaumeBrunerie this does indeed work! I wasn't aware of these; I truly appreciate the tip!

Assertion functions are designed for exactly this purpose. Simply use asserts condition instead of void for the return type of ensureNotFalsy, and it should work.
Here is an example:
function ensureNotFalsy(
  condition: any,
  errorMessage: string
): asserts condition {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error(errorMessage);
  }
}

const f = (orgRef: {organization?: {id?: string}} | null) => {
  ensureNotFalsy(orgRef, "Organization reference not found");
  ensureNotFalsy(orgRef.organization, "Organization not found");
  ensureNotFalsy(
    orgRef.organization.id,
    "Organization ID not found"
  );
}

Playground link
